# Как сделать из сцены на javaFX клиента общающегося с сервером на Jetty

Tags: java, javafx, сервер, jetty

Я знаю принцип работы javaFX и Jetty по отдельности. В интернете в большинстве примеров jetty работает с  браузером. Я хочу сделать клиента не в вебе а в javaFX
Как отправлять пост запросы по нажатию кнопок от клиента на сервер и как вообще происходит коннект к серверу

Раньше я все делал через Socket / SocketChannel а теперь хочу попробывать через Jetty ,но не знаю как это делать из javaFX

Может посоветуете статьи или какую-либо литературу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Pro JavaFX 9/Pro JavaFX 8 есть глава, описывающая принципы работы с веб-сервисами из JavaFX. 
Но JavaFX - это для разработки графических интерфейсов, чтобы "отправлять пост запросы" понадобится разобраться с разработкой HTTP клиента на Java (либо сразу использовать одну из многих библиотек, напр. OkHttp)